# how to change style of a css element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code:

```
  $('.signup-form-wrapper').css("style", "display: block");
                $('.login-form-wrapper').css("style", "display: none");
```

Not sure why it doesn't work. The element currently looks like this:

```
 <div class="signup-form-wrapper form-wrapper" style="display: none;">
```

I am trying to change this style to display: block, how do I do that?

Comment: This would work with `.attr("style", "display: block;")`, but most likely your intention is to use `.css("display", "block")` or just `.show()`

Comment: As an addendum I would suggest leaving as much CSS out of JQuery/javascript as possible, and instead assign a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.css()` itself sets the `style` of the element.

The function call syntax is:

```
$(elem).css('style-property','style-value');
```

change your code to:

```
$('.signup-form-wrapper').css("display", "block");
$('.login-form-wrapper').css("display", "none");
```

or for multiple styles for single element pass an object:

```
$(elem).css({'style-property1':'style-value1','style-property2':'style-value2'});
```

E.g.

```
$('.signup-form-wrapper').css({"display": "block", "border":"1px solid red"});
```

[JQuery `.css()` docs refererence](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 1):

You could change your code to either:

```
$('.signup-form-wrapper').show();
```

> This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'block'), except
>   that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/show/

or

```
$('.signup-form-wrapper').css({ display: 'block' });
```

> .css( properties )
>
> .css( propertyName, value )

Source: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value

Both will display your element and change the style.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.signup-form-wrapper').css("display", "block");
$('.login-form-wrapper').css("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for showing and hiding something there are shorter functions for that such as `.hide()` or `.show()`